# Replacing escaped string with another escaped string with sed

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu, awk, sed

I have .bashrc file and in the file this line appears:

`PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '`

And I'm trying to replace it with this:

`PS1='\[\e[32m\]\A\[\e[m\] \[\e[31m\]\u\[\e[m\]@\[\e[36m\]\h\[\e[m\]\[\e[32m\]:\[\e[m\]\[\e[32m\]\w\[\e[m\]\\$ '`

I tried to do this with:

`sed "s#PS1='\$\{debian_chroot:\+\(\$debian_chroot\)\}\\\[\\033\[01;32m\\\]\\u@\\h\\\[\\033\[00m\\\]:\\\[\\033\[01;34m\\\]\\w\\\[\\033\[00m\\\]\\\$ '#PS1='\\\[\\e[32m\\\]\\A\\\[\\e\[m\\\] \\\[\\e\[31m\\\]\\u\\\[\\e\[m\\\]@\\\[\\e\[36m\\\]\\h\\\[\\e\[m\\\]\\\[\\e\[32m\\\]:\\\[\\e\[m\\\]\\\[\\e\[32m\\\]\\w\\\[\\e\[m\\\]\\\\\$ '#g" .bashrc`

But I got error saying:

`sed: -e expression #1, char 267: Invalid content \{\}`

I'd use sed or any other bash/dash scripting way so I can make me a customization script for systems that I regularly use.

Thank you for help.

Comment: If that's the only `PS1=` line then just match on that delete it and add your desired line. Don't try to over-match.

Comment: Why using sed instead of editing the file manually ?

Comment: You can use script on many systems and it's always the same. I wish to avoid manual editing, that's why.

Comment: Sadly that's not only PS1= line. I'd do that normally :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|PS1='\''${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\\[\\033\[01;32m\\\]\\u@\\h\\\[\\033\[00m\\\]:\\\[\\033\[01;34m\\\]\\w\\\[\\033\[00m\\\]\\$ '\''|PS1='^''\\[\\e[32m\\]\\A\[\\e[m\\] \\[\\e[31m\\]\\u\\[\\e[m\\]@\\[\\e[36m\\]\\h\\[\\e[m\\]\\[\\e[32m\\]:\\[\\e[m\\]\\[\\e[32m\\]\\w\\[\\e[m\\]\\\\$ '\''|' file
```

Replace `'` by `'\''`  and `\` by `\\` in both the pattern and replacement and `[]` by `\[\]` in the pattern only.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do instead of weird ANSI codes :

```
PURPLE=$(tput setaf 5)
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
WHITE=$(tput setaf 7)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
CYAN=$(tput setaf 4)
LIGHT_CYAN=$(tput setaf 6)
STOP=$(tput sgr0)


PS1="\[$PURPLE\]\u\[$WHITE\]@\[$GREEN\]\h\[$WHITE\]:\[$GREEN\]\w\[$WHITE\] $ \[$STOP\]"
```

Finally to make a full reply to all the aspect of the question, :

```
sed -i '/^PS1=/d' ~/.bashrc # remove PS1 line in bashrc

# now feeding bashrc with goodies :
cat<<'EOF'>>~/.bashrc 
PURPLE=$(tput setaf 5)
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
WHITE=$(tput setaf 7)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
CYAN=$(tput setaf 4)
LIGHT_CYAN=$(tput setaf 6)
STOP=$(tput sgr0)

PS1="\[$PURPLE\]\u\[$WHITE\]@\[$GREEN\]\h\[$WHITE\]:\[$GREEN\]\w\[$WHITE\] $ \[$STOP\]"
EOF
```

Comment: This method is nice and useful. Thank you for sharing, but the original question still exists. How to replace original string with my or your string?